# "¿A qué fecha estamos hoy?" – is my Spanish learning app using real Spanish phrases?

Tags: preguntas

I'm using an app called LingoDeer to learn Spanish.

It teaches the following sentence:
"¿A qué fecha estamos hoy?".

A native speaker at work claims that this sentence sounds very artificial to them, and I also could not get Google Translate to produce that sentence with a variety of English inputs.

What's going on here? Is LingoDeer teaching wrong or uncommon phrases?

Comment: It's usual but it's wrong. [Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas.FECHA.3.a](https://www.rae.es/dpd/fecha).

Comment: @Rodrigo where in the link does it say that it is wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Decir "**A qué fecha estamos hoy**" es **correcto**.

> Saying "**A qué fecha estamos hoy**" is **correct**.

Lo siento por discrepar, pero en España es común referirse de distintas maneras a la fecha tales como;

> I'm sorry for disagreeing, but in Spain it is common to refer to the
> date in different ways such as;

"**A qué fecha estamos hoy**"

- ¿A qué fecha estamos? / ¿Qué fecha estamos (hoy)? significa ¿qué día es hoy?
- ¿Qué fecha estamos hoy del 2022?
- ¿Hoy, a qué estamos?
- ¿Mañana a qué amanecemos?
- ¿A qué somos (hoy)?
- ¿A cuántos estamos (hoy)?
- ¿Qué día es hoy?.
- ¿La fecha de hoy?
- ¿Cuál es el día de hoy?
- ¿Qué día es (hoy)?
- A qué (día) estamos?
- ¿Qué fecha es en el calendario?
- ¿Qué número de día del año es hoy?

Son todas expresiones que se pueden escuchar a diario, según la zona donde vivas. Así que considero que es una expresión valida, quizás utilizada más en unos sitios que en otros, pero válida al fin y al cabo.

> They are all expressions that can be heard daily, depending on the
> area where you live. So I consider that it is a valid expression,
> perhaps used more in some places than in others, but valid after all.

**P.D.** Ejemplos de fecha

> Date Examples

**A qué fecha estamos**

> What is the date

https://www.ingles.com/ejemplos/a%20que%20fecha%20estamos

[image]

Comment: Con respecto a la/al colega de Ynv, muchos hablantes nativos tanto angloparlantes como hispanohablantes creen que por saber lo que suena bien en su propio dialecto, ya saben lo que es correcto en todo el mundo. Lo he visto muchas veces en aplicaciones de aprendizaje de idiomas. P. ej. "in hospital" puede parecer un error flagrante en EE. UU., pero es perfectamente normal en Reino Unido.

Comment: No se dice ''in hospital'' en EE. UU?  Qué dicen en lugar de eso?

Comment: En Chile es habitual escuchar "¿A cuánto estamos hoy?" y la expresión "¿A qué fecha estamos?" no me suena particularmente extraña

Answer (score 3):

*¿A qué fecha estamos?* sounds really bad. If my daughter said that I would correct her.

The following sound natural:

- *¿En qué fecha estamos?*
- *¿A qué fecha te refieres?*

Answer (score 3):

It is correct and usual, at least in my variety of Spanish (Spain). The preposition 'a' is used with weekdays and dates, as in these examples:

```
Hoy estamos a lunes.
Hoy estamos a 19 de diciembre.
```

So, in order to turn these statements into question form, we have to replace 'lunes' with 'qué día' or '19 de diciembre' with 'qué fecha':

```
¿Hoy estamos a qué día (de la semana)?
¿Hoy estamos a qué fecha?
```

But the more natural word order in Spanish questions requires moving the interrogative expression to the front of the sentence, which gives us the following more common questions:

```
¿A qué día (de la semana) estamos hoy?
¿A qué fecha estamos hoy?
```

On top of that, the word 'día'/'fecha' is often omitted, resulting in the very common question:

```
¿A qué estamos (hoy)?
```

This is the way I would typically ask the question if, for example, I'm filling out a form in front of somebody and I'm unsure about the date.

Answer (score 1):

He escuchado

*¿A qué fecha estamos hoy?*

varias veces en España (al menos en ciertas regiones), pero puede que no sea exactamente correcto.

Yo probablemente diría

*¿En qué fecha estamos?*

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, it isn't the most natural, but it also isn't artificial enough for it to sound as 'textbook phrase'. You could provide us with more examples in order to make a correct assessment of the artificiality of the sentences.

Answer (score 0):

As a Latin-American Spanish speaker, I never heard "A que fecha...".

Always "Que fecha..." or "En que fecha..."

Probably that's for Spain